Project tab does not show all the files/folders in Unity Editor after build APK file
I'm learning Unity Editor. After I had build my application to test on android device. Most of my folders and files in Assets were lost in Project tab. I can still see it in Explorer but Unity Editor refuse to show it.
Before build:enter image description here
After build: enter image description here
How can I enable those files/folders back again ?

Folders do not disappear by themselves. Check the availability of your folders directly in the project directory via windows/mac. If they are not there, then it means you were careless and your folders were deleted forever. If folders are present in this directory, but are not displayed in Unity, check Unity for errors, because Unity uses caching and compilation, but if any errors prevent this, then you should first solve them. Open the console in Unity and check for red errors.

Press Ctrl+U to open Editor History in Unity Editor, you can back to specific action there. Or You can use version control (such as git) to manage and backup your work.
